# outlook does not forward gmail-domained email

Tags: outlook, gmail, mail-server

I have my email **user@example.com** on outlook. I have made rules to forward ALL messages to **user@gmail.com**.

If I send an email from **user@company.com** to **user@example.com** it will end up to **user@gmail.com**. so I am happy.

if I send an email from **user2@gmail.com** to **user@example.com** it does not end up to **user@gmail.com** and stays at **user@example.com**. Therefore I believe the problem is about Gmail-domained emails.

Don't you think this is a problem from outlook ? if so what can I do ? I am the admin.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I cannot get this to work either.  It even says "Email is being forwarded to XXX@gmail.com" every time I open Outlook - but of course, it isn't.